# can not populate boostrap calendar using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the following libraries,

```
Angularjs
boostrap
datepair https://jonthornton.github.io/Datepair.js/
jQuery timepicker
```

I'm building a leave request application where employees can schedule time off by selecting start date, start time, end time, end date. I'm using Jon Thornton's datepair to auto populate the end date and end time. I've been able to successfully get this to all work.

I'm experiencing an issue populating the calendar field with the scope when the field value is preexisting in the database.

Code example.

```
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div id="requestForm" xp-datepair>
                <input type="text" class="date start" ng-model="startDate" xp-datepicker required /> 
                <label>Start Time</label> 
                <input type="text" class="time start" ng-model="startTime" xp-timepicker required /> 
                <label>End Time</label>
                <input type="text" class="time end" ng-model="endTime" xp-timepicker required /> 
                <label>End Date</label>
                <input type="text" class="date end" ng-model="endDate" xp-datepicker required />
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

js

```
angular
  .module('xp-timepicker', [])
  .directive('xpTimepicker', timepicker)
  .directive('xpDatepicker', datepicker)
  .directive('xpDatepair', datepair);

function datepair() {   
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
        new Datepair(element[0]);
      }
    }; 
}

function timepicker() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.timepicker({
        showDuration: true,
        timeFormat: 'g:ia'
      });
    }
  };
}

function datepicker() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.datepicker({
                'format' : 'MM/dd/yyyy',
                'autoclose' : true
            });
        }
    };
}

angular
  .module('app', ['xp-timepicker'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.startDate = '01/12/2016';
    $scope.endDate = '01/12/2016';

    $scope.startTime = '7:00pm';
    $scope.endTime = '8:00pm';
  });
```

I should see the calendar field populated with 01/12/2016, but it appears to be blank. The time however appears to be working perfectly. Interestingly if I populate the input value rather than ng-model, it appears to work.

plunker [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/CoZjcFlFGR4ZWoPLPFPc?p=preview).

Comment: You're saving a string, what you should do is set a Date object with the desired date

Comment: @AlonEitan the use of new Date() inplace of the string doesn't appear to work either.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you were using bootstrap datepicker, and that's how you do it with that model (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

Comment: I would love to use the angular ui version, I just can't figure out how to get it to work with datepair.

Comment: There's also this model - https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker as you can see in the [examples](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex2) it also support start and end date&time

Comment: Thanks, but it's important we keep the times too.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, but that's why I also included the example that use both date and time (http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex2) - I'm using this model and it works great

Comment: Sorry I missed that, thanks.

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem with uibootstrap at the moment. Did you ever manage to solve this issue?